# Placing absolute box at the end of text (flexible by length of text)

Tags: html, css, layout

I want to place an absolute popup box at the end of text link.

HTML

```
<div style="float:left;">Hello World</div><div class="box">BOX</div>
```

CSS

```
.box
{
    float:left;
    border-color:#000;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    width:80px;
    height:80px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/7N6ye/1/

It works fine only when a box is relative. When I set `position:absolute` on the box, it looks like

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/7N6ye/3/

Any ideas? Eventually, I'll have a list of links each of which has different text length. (And each box will popup at the end of text).

Comment: Absolute positioning is absolute - by definition, it can't be relative to other elements in the document flow.

Comment: How much text will be in the pop-up box?

Comment: @Adrian Thanks for the definition. As you know, default position of Absolute is usually as same as relative(but floating from layout panels). That's what I want to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work:

```
<div  class="box">Hello World<div>BOX</div></div>
```

with the CSS:

```
.box {
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid red;
    float: left;
}
.box div
{
    position:absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    border-color:#000;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    width:80px;
    height:80px;
    text-align:center;
    display: inline-box;
}
```

Fiddle Reference: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/DWe8B/

**Notes**

(1) I nested the popup box within the text line.  I can work around that.
the problem is that the popup inherits the width of the parent, so the box
can be quite narrow unless you specify a width.

Comment: That's what I really want. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you set the position to relative, the div is put relative to its original position.
e.g. 100px to the left from where you are

If you set the position to absolute, the div is put relative to its parent (the next parent with relative or absolute positioning).
e.g. 100px from the left corner of the parent

on top of that the div is no longer part of the document flow. So other elements can overlap with it.

The same is true for floating elements. Here the next available position is used.

In general it makes no sense to set absolute positioning as well as a float.